# node.js read value from self - exported object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a big js object that looks like this (truncated)

```
var argData = module.exports = {
    SetName: {
    definitions: [
        { name: 'clientMacAddress', alias: 'c', type: String },
        { name: 'name', alias: 'n', type: String }
    ],
    usage: [
        {
            header: 'blah',
            content: 'blah'
        },
        {
            header: 'Options',
            optionList: [
                { name: 'clientMacAddress', alias: 'c', type: String },
                { name: 'name', alias: 'n', type: String }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
...
```

As you can see, everything in argData["SetName"].definitions is in the optionList section. I would like to just sub in a variable in the optionsList section so it looks like this:

```
...
header: 'Options',
        //already tried doing this and it didn't work
        optionList: argData["SetLatency"].definitions
    }
...
```

I want to refer to a key in the object within itself (if that makes sense). I tried "self.argData" but that didn't work. I'm thinking that because I'm declaring it here, it's not possible to do a variable, but I want to make sure. If not, what would be the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the common code in variable (.i.e: keys ) before the export :

```
const keys =  [
                { name: 'clientMacAddress', alias: 'c', type: String },
                { name: 'name', alias: 'n', type: String }
            ];

var argData = module.exports = {
    SetName: {
    definitions: keys,
    usage: [
        {
            header: 'blah',
            content: 'blah'
        },
        {
            header: 'Options',
            optionList: keys
        }
    ]
}
...
```